# Where do you initialize property values in a View Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, segue

I have a view controller with properties that determine its behaviour.  These are set by its parent in `prepareForSegue`.

The potential bug this induces in my program is that the parent in question is not guaranteed to set the properties, so I would like to have a default value.  On researching, I now understand that properties in Objective C don't have default values.  This left me with the following options:

- Set the default values for properties in the child view's `viewDidLoad` method.  However, on investigation, `viewDidLoad` is called *after* `prepareForSegue` in the parent - so I would be overwriting the parent's values when the parent actually does set the properties.
- I then thought I could use `(id) init` to initialize the values, but, at least when using storyboards, this method isn't called at all!

I may have a workaround in that objects will initialize to a default value, but in this case all I want to pass in is a BOOL.  And since the bool will have *some value* even if not initialized correctly, I can't test it to see if it is non-nil.

Are there any opportunities for initializing value in the child view controller before `prepareForSegue` in the parent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overriding `init` will not help as it is not the designated initialiser for `UIViewController` objects. When manually instantiating a view controller `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle` is called, when loaded from a storyboard `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder` will be called. If you want to set properties when the view controller is initialised you have to override both initialisers.

> On researching, I now understand that properties in Objective C don't have default values.

They do. `nil` for objects, `0` for integer values, `0.0` for floating points etc. If you need default values other than that you should set them in the appropriate init method.

Comment: You have to override *both*? That may be the clunkiest thing I've seen in Objective C so far.  It's sad there isn't a hook like `viewDidLoad` that you can execute before external actors can message your view controller.

Comment: It's very unusual to have to override both. Most objects either come from storyboards or they don't. If they come from storyboards, then overriding `initWithCoder:` (or awakeFromNib) is sufficient. If you are writing an extremely reusable piece of code, it is not uncommon to create a `-setup` method that can be called from both initialization paths. But in many cases, careful selection of property meanings can make the default values work (0, NO, nil, etc), so you don't need to initialize them anyway. In practice, I don't find it comes up all that often.

Comment: So maybe I don't understood - do I have to override just one or both to achieve what I'm looking for with initializers?

Comment: @Rob - there was a comment on a previously now-deleted answer that was also helpful that way.  I didn't realize BOOL was guaranteed to be initialized to 0 and yes, I can make what I want work with that info.  My follow-on about initializing just one or both is more so I understand how this part of iOS works.

Comment: If you want to be able to use the view controller both from storyboards and manually allocated, then you have to override both. If you only ever use storyboards, overriding `initWithCoder:` is sufficient.